# How can I set the table model for a JTable from another component's listener?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jtree

I have created two JPanels. One JPanel has a JTree with nodes. The other JPanel has a SQL filled JTable. I'm trying to get the node selection from the JTree to re-run the query for the JTable with the input from the JTree providing part of the filter for the JTable. Can you please provide guidance? I'm new to Java. Here is the code for the question:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class SCCEEforTreeAndTableInteraction {

    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;
    private static ResultSet rs = null;
    private static ResultSetMetaData meta;
    private static int columnCount = 0;
    private static int rowCount = 0;
    private static Object[][] result;
    private static String[] columnNames;
    private static JTree tree;
    public static Hashtable<Object, Integer> treeData;
    public int tableTopicNodeID;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create and setup window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tree and Table Interaction");
        JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel treePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, treePanel, tablePanel);
        split.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        myJTree tree = new myJTree();
        myJTable table = new myJTable();
        frame.add(panelMain);
        treePanel.add(tree);
        tablePanel.add(table);
        panelMain.add(split);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panelMain.setVisible(true);
        treePanel.setVisible(true);
        tablePanel.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }

    private static class myJTable extends JPanel {
        //Getting the data from the database in order to fill the table
        public myJTable() {
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/FlamingDartDB;create=true;user=user;password=password");
                stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

                rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from FLAMINGDART.TOPICDATA where NODEID =" + *Start with a default, then get data from the listener below*); //NodeID should be different every time I select a node
                rs.beforeFirst();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
                }
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from FLAMINGDART.TOPICDATA where NODEID =3");//NodeID should be different every time I select a node
                meta = rs.getMetaData();
                columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();   //The first 2 column are not for display to the user
                columnNames = new String[columnCount];
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    columnNames[i] = meta.getColumnName(i + 1);
                }
                result = new Object[rowCount][columnCount];
                rs.beforeFirst();
                for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    rs.next();
                    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                        result[i][j] = rs.getObject(j + 1);
                    }
                }
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
                sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
            }
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(result, columnNames);
            JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
            JScrollPane topicTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            topicTableScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            add(topicTableScrollPane);
        }
    }

    private static class myJTree extends JPanel implements TreeSelectionListener {

        public myJTree() {
            //This is sample tree data with the node ID that is used to refine the table query.
            treeData = new Hashtable();
            treeData.put("Node 1", new Integer(1));
            treeData.put("Node 2", new Integer(2));
            treeData.put("Node 3", new Integer(3));
            treeData.put("Node 4", new Integer(4));
            treeData.put("Node 5", new Integer(5));
            treeData.put("Node 6", new Integer(6));
            treeData.put("Node 7", new Integer(7));
            treeData.put("Node 8", new Integer(8));
            treeData.put("Node 9", new Integer(9));
            tree = new JTree(treeData);
            tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
            tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
            this.add(tree);
        }

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent tse) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeSelected = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
            if (nodeSelected == null) //Nothing is selected.     
            {
                System.out.println("Selected Node is Null");
                return;
            }
            Integer n = treeData.get(nodeSelected.getUserObject());//Returns the integer value associated with the key from the node table
            if (n != null) {
                System.out.println("Start a new query with " + n + " as a filter for the query.");
 *//This is supposed to set the node id that helps populate the table with a new query. Something along the lines of table.SetTableModel(n) that I'm having trouble implementing.*
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/), although the JDBC isn't essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TreeSelectionListener`, use an instance of [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to update your `JTable`'s `TableModel` in the background. More examples may be found [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).